# Conversion of Decimal to Binary number with all the test Cases

Tags: c++

Here's my Implementation i take the number and put it into the stack by doing mathematical calculation ... but it's not producing correct output even my logic regarding the problem is correct ... 
Please detect what is wrong in my implementation. It's competitive programming Question asked by two companies in my College . So, please help me to correct the implementation.... 
**I only want to know what is wrong with my implementation .....**

**Actual Question:
Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. There will be a single line for each testcase which contains N.
Output:
Print all binary numbers with decimal values from 1 to N in a single line.
Constraints:
1 ≤ T ≤ 106
1 ≤ N ≤ 106**

Example:
Input:
2
2
5

Output:
1 10
1 10 11 100 101

Explanation:
Testcase 1: Binary numbers from 1 to 2 are 1 and 10.

This is the Required Output 
Input:
2
2
5

Output:
1 10
1 10 11 100 101

And my output is :
For Input:
1
3
Your Output is:

Can any one here tell me the reason of incorrect output ..

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stack> 
#include <queue> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T ;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        int  n;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {   
            stack <int > s;
            int num=i;
            while(num>0)
            {  
                s.push(num%2);
                num=num/2 ;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<s.size();j++)
            {
                cout<<s.top();
                s.pop();
            }
            cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
return 0
```

This is the Required Output

```
Input:
2
2
5

Output:
1 10
1 10 11 100 101
```

And my output is :

```
For Input:
1
3
Your Output is:
```

Can any one here tell me the reason of incorrect output ..

Comment: If it were a function, it would be a lot easier for you to write the tests. Looking.

Comment: Same happen in case of Function .... the problem is with output don't know i am right or Wrong .. but i also tried with function got the same error in output

Comment: `for(int j=0;i<s.size();j++)` -> `for(int j=0;j<s.size();j++)`. You are checking `i` instead of `j` in the termination criterion. Voting to close as typo. But this is something that you could've found easily with [some debugging](https://godbolt.org/z/5m03WM) or even easier by stepping through your code in a debugger.

Comment: This doesn't produce the output you claim.

Comment: For Input:
2
2
5
Your Output is:
1 1 
1 1 1 10 10   output is still incorrect ...

Comment: Please edit your comments instead of adding new ones when you want to amend them. (You can do that for 5 minutes after posting them).

Comment: For clarification you should [edit]  your question and not post tons of comments

Comment: @ Kenny Ostrom ..its giving output but the output is incorrect and i tried my best to find the mistake in my implementation .. if you are able to detect then please correct the above Implementation

Comment: I feel urge to flag this as duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @Jabberwocky  . I already edited my Post i only want to know why my implementation is not producing correct output.. Even my Logic is correct .. Help me about their is something wrong with my logic or with y output

Comment: @Yksisarvinen ... I already edited my Post i only want to know why my implementation is not producing correct output.. Even my Logic is correct .. Help me about their is something wrong with my logic or with y output

Comment: It would help a lot if you could describe what the program is supposed to do instead of making  people guess from an example.

Comment: `j<s.size()` is not a very good condition when you're modifying `s` inside the loop...

Comment: @molbdnilo hey i edited my question. yes but both loops work separately regarding j<s.size()

Comment: Reread molbdnilo's last comment.

Comment: @Kenny Ostrom if it's  creating the problem then then in output i supposed to segmentation Fault but it's Working Fine and See again my implementation popping loop is different and pushing loop is different .. i think it's the only advantage of Vector

Comment: @sanjjeevdutt There are no situations where you are *supposed* to get a segmentation fault.

Comment: (1) Please post code that compiles.  The code you posted is missing a `;` and a `}`. (2) Please tell us what output you are getting.  Are you getting ***no** output?*  You seem to be saying that your output is `Your Output is:` — is that what you’re saying? (3) The biggest problem in your code has been pointed out in a comment, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int j=0;j<s.size();j++)
{
    cout<<s.top();
    s.pop();
}
```

Suppose `s` has four elements.
On the first iteration, `j` is 0 and `s.size()` is 4.
On the second, `j` is 1 and `s.size()` is 3.
On the third, `j` is 2 and `s.size()` is 2, so the loop terminates.
That's two iterations instead of four.

Instead of counting the times you're going to pop, just pop until the stack is empty:

```
while (!s.empty())
{
    cout << s.top();
    s.pop();
}
```